# Which WPF project template should I choose for VS 2019?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2019.

For VS 2013 --- File => New => Project => WPF Application.

For VS 2019 --- File => New => Project => ???

For VS 2019, which WPF project template should I choose?

Comment: There is no "right" answer to this question; it's entirely up to you. Just depends on whether you want to use .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content below was written in 2019. Things have (unsurprisingly) improved. The advice these days is just go with the latest .NET version. Forget about .NET Framework: if you need to use it for some reason, you're not asking this question.

---

If you're creating an application (and not a library), then choose one of:

- WPF App (.NET Framework)
- WPF App (.NET Core)

Whether you choose .NET Framework or .NET Core depends on many things. .NET Core is the newer technology, but the development experience (for WPF + .NET Core) in Visual Studio is still a bit rough around the edges, so if you're not sure then go for .NET Framework.

Comment: When you say "rough around the edges" what do you mean? I am facing this exact problem right now and not sure if to start a new wpf project with .net 6 or .net framework

Comment: This post is 3 years old. The development experience is sorted. Go with the latest .net version.